# There is no bold text, italics in IEEEtran (using xepersian)?

Tags: ieeetran, bold, persian

I have a problem of non-working `\textbf`, `\bfseries` commands (and almost all changing fontstyle commands) in Persian document (in English, everything is okay) in `\documentclass[journal,onecolumn,11pt,a4,draftcls,doublespace]`{IEEEtran}.

What should I do?

Also, Note that other commands like  `\textit \slshape` don't work. And section numberings are also squared shape, and even the word "draft" in the left-side of the footnote is also square.

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn,11pt,a4,draftcls,doublespace]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{B Nazanin} 
\setlatintextfont[Scale=0.98]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}


\begin{latin}
\title{\protect{fff}}

\author{\protect{hamed, \emph{Student}\\
xx University of Technology }}


\IEEEspecialpapernotice{\protect{(Advanced ss Term Project Report)}}

\maketitle
\end{latin}

\section{\textbf{مقدمه}}

 شبکه‌های بیسیم آینده باید در آنِ واحد قادر باشند، که میلیاردها دستگاه را مدیریت کنند؛ که هر کدام نیازمند نرخ
گذردهی بالایی برای پشتیبانی از بسیاری از برنامه‌های کاربردی از قبیل صدا (\lr{Voice})، ویدئو بلادرنگ،  فیلم‌های با کیفیت بالا هستند.



\end{document}
```

[image: this is a screen shot of what i get. thanks]

Comment: Try with another font, I have no problem with `Amiri` font